# Evaluating a Func<T> delegate via a property within the type's generic object

Tags: c#, func

I am having some difficulty in trying to make a `Func<T>` expression evaluate a property within an object instance, e.g.

```
var t = new Transition<ILexeme>( 1, () => TokenType == eToken.TOKEN_COMMENT );
```

The Visual Studio compiler complains with a **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or, property 'ILexeme.TokenType.get'** error, because it's expecting an `ILexeme` object instance.

What I am attempting to do is create a state machine that uses `Func<T>` to invoke the transition function's delegate, which tests to see if the value of the `eToken` property matches the `eToken` within the token stream.  If it is equal the machine moves onto the next state.

The problem is I am passing in `ILexeme` as the generic type to the `Transition` class, but I want the transition function to use a property within the generic type, i.e. `TokenType`.  My question is how can I achieve this bearing
in mind that it **must** work for value types, i.e. `char`, `int`, etc?

Here is the definition for ILexeme:

```
public interface ILexeme
{
    eToken TokenType { get; }
    String TokenString { get; }
}
```

And here is the concrete implementation of ILexeme:

```
public enum eToken : int
{
    TOKEN_COMMENT,
    TOKEN_SEPARATOR
}

public class Token : ILexeme
{
    public eToken TokenType { get; }
    public String TokenString { get; }
}
```

And this is the definition for Transition:

```
public readonly int FromState;
public readonly int ToState;
public readonly Func<T> Input;

public Transition( int fromState, Func<T> input, int toState )
{
    this.FromState = fromState;
    this.ToState = toState;
    this.Input = input;
}
```

Comment: The quoted compiler error means that you can't say just `TokenType` in the current context. You need to use `someObjectInstance.TokenType`. Are you inside a static method?

Comment: Maybe you meant `Func<T, bool>`, then your lambda would be: `lexeme => lexeme.TokenType == eToken.TOKEN_COMMENT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have written your lambda expression incorrectly. Since `TokenType` is an instance property, you should pass an instance of an object to the lambda. Right now it's parameterless. So, I think it should be something like

```
var t = new Transition<ILexeme>( 1, eTok => eTok.TokenType == eToken.TOKEN_COMMENT );
```

And the Transition class

```
public readonly int FromState;
public readonly int ToState;
public readonly Func<T, bool> Input;

public Transition( int fromState, Func<T, bool> input, int toState )
{
    this.FromState = fromState;
    this.ToState = toState;
    this.Input = input;
}
```

Also, you might want to introduce second type parameter to `Transition` class, so it becomes  something quite general:

```
class Transition<TInput, TResult> {
public readonly int FromState;
public readonly int ToState;
public readonly Func<T, TResult> Input;

public Transition( int fromState, Func<T, TResult> input, int toState )
{
    this.FromState = fromState;
    this.ToState = toState;
    this.Input = input;
}
}
```

If it's the case, you might want to place some type constraints using [where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @JOHN, plinth: I have tried your suggestion and it worked.  +1 to both of you.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your `Transition<ILexeme>`-constructor, you expect a `Func<ILexeme>` but you provide a `Func<bool>`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because TokenType is a property on the type ILexeme, but in your call to the constructor there is no valid instance of that type.  Perhaps you want your declaration to be

```
public Transition(int fromState, Func<T, bool>, int toState) { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can write your code to be:

```
var t = new Transition<ILexeme>(1, lex => lex.TokenType == eToken.TOKEN_COMMENT, 2);
```